# Submit form by clicking link in liferay

Tags: hyperlink, liferay, liferay-6

I am working with liferay 6.0.6 . I need to provide a link in my email , so that By clicking that link user should be able to take some values to a portlet form and should submit that form .Please give me a solution.

Comment: Using `PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(PortletRequest portletRequest, String portletName, long plid,String lifecycle)` , you can create url which will render your portlet[jsp with form] in some layout. Provide this url in mail.

Comment: This is working fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please  find the following code

```
String userName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "userName");
        System.out.println("userName "+userName);
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        PortletURL portletUrl;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
        long plid = 0L;
        Layout layout = themeDisplay.getLayout();
         plid = layout.getPlid();
         PortletDisplay portletDisplay= themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay();
         String portletID= portletDisplay.getId();
       // plid = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), true, "/Add Participants").getPlid();
        portletUrl = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(httpRequest, "urlportlet_WAR_UrlTestportlet", plid, PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE);
        portletUrl.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.NORMAL);
        portletUrl.setParameter("javax.portlet.action", "addUser");
        portletUrl.setParameter("userName", "krishnamohan");
        String url = portletUrl.toString();
        System.out.println("url  ---->   "+ url);
```